# Overrdding the OnCreateOptionsMenu method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, oncreateoptionsmenu

I'm currently trying to create a basic action bar in my app. I'm trying to override the onCreateOptionsMenu method in my Main Activity but am getting an error that "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype". However, I see in the 'Activity' class definition (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) that it does contain the method. So, please help me understand why i'm not able to override the method?

Here's the MainActivity class code along with all the imports:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
     {
         //Inflate the menu. this adds items to the action bar if it is present
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
         return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
     {
         switch(item.getItemId())
         {
             case R.id.action_create_order:
                 //Code to run when the create order item is clicked
                 Intent intent=new Intent(this,OrderActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
                 return true;
             case R.id.action_settings:
                 //Code to run when the settings item is clicked
                 return true;
             default:
                 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }
     }


 }
```

Comment: try changing `OnCreateOptionsMenu` to `onCreateOptionsMenu`. replace the `O` (Caps) with `o` (lower case)

Comment: oops:)...Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are trying to override a method which doesn't exist in the base class. Methods in java is case sensitive. Hence OnCreateOptionsMenu and onCreateOptionsMenu are different methods. Change the method name to onCreateOptionsMenu and it will work.